# PyQt5 connect to Websocket - wait for signal from server

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to connect to a scanner which offers a REST Api over an apiport. Before I can do that I have to connect to the Scanner using PyQt5 and sign a challange. I have a C++ code as example but I can not find the corresponding PyQt Classes/Methods.

Basically I am looking for a way to replace these lines from C++:

```
QWebSocket socket;
QString address = "127.0.0.1";
QString port = "1234";
connect(&socket,&QWebSocket::textMessageReceived,this,&Client::onTextMessageReceived);
socket.open(QUrl(QString("ws://%1:%2").arg(address).arg(port)));
```

My problem is this line:

```
connect(&socket,&QWebSocket::textMessageReceived,this,&Client::onTextMessageReceived);
```

Can someone help me on this one?
All I have till now is this: (but it throws the Error:
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable)

```
class Client(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.client =  QtWebSockets.QWebSocket("",QtWebSockets.QWebSocketProtocol.Version13,None)
        #self.client.error.connect(self.error)
        print("Trigger")
        trigger = self.client.textMessageReceived()


        #self.client.open(QUrl("ws://"+UDP_IP+":"+str(notificationsport)))

    def ontextmsgreceived():
        print("Text MSG received")

    def close(self):
        self.client.close()




global client
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
client = Client(app)
app.exec_()
```

Thanks a lot for your Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyQt the connection syntax is the following:

C++:

```
connect(sender, &Class_sender::some_signal, receiver, &Class_receiver::some_slot);
```

python:

```
sender.some_signal.connect(receiver.some_slot)
```

so in your case:

```
self.client.textMessageReceived.connect(self.ontextmsgreceived)
```

Another problem is that your slot is a method of the class so the first parameter must be the `self`, in addition the [textMessageReceived](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#textMessageReceived) signal sends a text as a parameter, so the slot must have the same parameter:

```
def ontextmsgreceived(self, message):
    print("Text MSG received", message)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works very well!

Comment: @benschbob91  If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour]